# How can I fix an Access Database missing references, libaries, and objects on Windows 7 Ulti 64bit

Tags: database, ms-access, reference, vba

Recently I've been given an Access database program to fix from my father, it's an invoicing program, so I can't exactly give it out freely. 
Unfortunately I know very little about Access and programming.

I'm fairly sure the developer of this database/program has used quite an old version of Visual Basic, I suspect either 5.0 or 6.0.

I've figured out to open the database file in the Visual Basic editor that comes with Access 2003 and 2010. One of the references state:

> MISSING: Microsoft Windows Common Controls 5.0 (SP2)
>   Location: C:\WINDOWS\system32\COMCTL32.OCX
>   Language: Standard

However there are various other problems, such as some of the buttons not working fully, such as when ignoring the references problem starting up the database creates a popup that states:

> There is no object in this control.

The Customers and Orders buttons seem to work fine, however clicking the reports button causes the program to create another popup that says:

> Object doesn't support this property or method.

This popup appears twice.

The report function essentially does: Date From and Date To, using a calender date picker. This then shows the user the orders between those two dates and totals them. At first the Date To calender element seems to work, but the user needs to type into the Form field, normally the calender appears for the user to select from.

As said the calender in the report function does not appear, I suspect this is because it is related to a DirectX component/element that was built on Vista?

Clicking the export customer file button also creates the Object doesn't support this property or method pop up message.

How can I fix this? Is it just a bunch of adjustments needed because of the move from Windows Vista to Windows 7.

Comment: Years ago, faced with a similar issue and not having time to modify code, I found a copy of the that OCX, placed onto the PC and then registered it. That's the quickest way out. Otherwise, you need to replace the functionality of the OCX with the newer technology -- which may be an issue if you are not a VBA programmer.

Comment: It's impossible for us to debug code that you haven't included, and questions asking us to speculate on possible causes for vaguely described problems are not appropriate here. You're asking us to just post wild guesses as to what your code might or might not need to fix a problem you can't state clearly. "I get some kind of message that talks about 'The Object doesn't support this property or method' pops up. What can cause it?". If you've managed to load the app in the VBA editor, start by replacing the reference (the MISSING) with the proper version. (continued)

Comment: This may solve some of your "Object doesn't support" errors. Then set breakpoints on where the errors occur, use the debugger to run to the breakpoint, and figure out which variables are causing the issue, and then you can post a specific question here which includes *the relevant code* and ask us how to solve that problem. Solving one may help you figure out how to solve many (or all) of the others. You have to do some basic troubleshooting yourself first though, so that you can include the details we can use to help. See [help/how-to-ask] for some pointers.

Comment: Is there a safe way to demonstrate the code then?

Comment: Lets start with basics. When Access encounters an error in the VBA code and pops up a message, you can hit CTL+Break, select 'Debug' and that will take you to the line of code having the error. Next, you would need to post: (1) that line of code; (2) The exact error message and number; (C) the values of all variables used in that line of code (either hover cursor over variable, or in the 'Immediate Window' type '?varxxxName' and press enter. Unfortunately, you may need to post much more info.

Comment: I downloaded the COMCTL32.OCX zip file which is the Microsoft Windows Common Controls 5.0 SP2 from here: http://www.martin2k.co.uk/vb6/vb6download4.php After extracting this to my own personal Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit computer the program works completely fine. As in it does everything it's supposed to with seemingly no errors at all. The calender works, the reports and customers button works, even the export customers to a file, but here's the weird thing. Despite replicating my steps, on a different Win7 64 bit machine, starting the database gives the "There is no object in this control"

Comment: which pops up upon first load, secondly the export to file button doesn't work. I guess I can paste the code here. Additionally like I said early it works fine on my main PC, just not the intended one with Win7, the references on both PCs NO LONGER report the Windows Common controls 5.0 as MISSING.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/cbSybaXk I guess I need to make a new comment after five minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I would first suggest you determine if the calendar control is using the common dialog control, or using the ActiveX calendar control that was supplied with Access (up to 2003). While versions of Access after 2007 can use the ActiveX calendar control, it is NOT included with the install. The result here is if your application is dependent on the ActiveX control, the you best stick to using Access 2003. Also keep in mind that during the initial access 2003 install, you need to INCLUDE the calendar control (it is not included by default).

Your broken reference issue(s) can be resolved in about 5 minutes by anyone with Access experience. So once in VBA, I would first set a reference to the common dialog control. If you don’t have version 5, pick the most highest version you have on your computer.

However, for the most part competent developers AVOID using and including such references in their applications (and your troubles now quite much vindicate this good developer practice). In fact I don’t think an Access install ALSO includes a common dialog library. Any  VB5 or VB6 application install DOES include the library – but we don’t see a lot of VB6 applications installed, and thus you could in fact be missing that library.

The FileDilog (to browse for a selected file) or a “calendar” to select a date range etc. can be accomplished without a reference to the common dialog control.

Here is a good article on how to resolve reference problems:

http://www.accessmvp.com/djsteele/AccessReferenceErrors.html